# Notification sound not plays when notification received in release apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio, notifications

I will provide the RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound object to sound property of channel but my phone only vibrates not play sound when notification received in release apk but in build apk it works fine why?

Here is the code

```
 const AndroidNotificationChannel channel2 = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'sunrise_channel',
    'Sunrise Channel',
    description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
    importance: Importance.high,
    sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('morning'),
  );
```